# iOS Container with multiple views

Tags: ios, storyboard

I am trying to create a View that has a container in it. On that View, I want to switch between a table view and a map view. Yelp's app does exactly what I'm looking to do.

The problem I'm running into is switching between the views. Here is how my storyboard is set up:

[image: Storyboard]

I created a controller that is used to switch between the table and the map. The problem is if I use a modal or custom segue, it takes over the whole view.

I've tried embedding them in a navigation controller which does work (I think), but then once the user clicks on something in the controller I need to take them out of that navigation controller and back into the main navigation.

Comment: http://engineeringblog.yelp.com/2013/11/whoa-that-embedded-web-view-looks-hot-in-your-ios-app.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this, is to make the SwitchViewController a custom container controller, and add either the table view or map view as its child. Here is an example that I've used before that has the same set up as your storyboard (my ContainerViewController is your SwitchViewController, and my controllers with the identifiers "InitialVC" and "substituteVC" would be your table view and map view). 
This is code I have in the ContainerViewController,

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    UIViewController *initial = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"InitialVC"];
    [self addChildViewController:initial];
    [self.view addSubview:initial.view];
    self.currentController = initial;
    [self constrainViewEqual:self.currentController];
}

-(void)switchToNewView {
    UIViewController *sub = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SubstituteVC"];
    [self addChildViewController:sub];
    sub.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
    [self moveToNewController:sub];
}

-(void)moveToNewController:(UIViewController *) newController {
    [self.currentController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
    [self transitionFromViewController:self.currentController toViewController:newController duration:.6 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^{}
         completion:^(BOOL finished) {
             [self.currentController removeFromParentViewController];
             [newController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
             self.currentController = newController;
             [self constrainViewEqual:self.currentController];
         }];
}
```

constrainViewEqual is a category method that I use to set up the layout constraints for the views. It looks like this,

```
-(void)constrainViewEqual:(UIViewController *) vc {
    [vc.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    NSLayoutConstraint *con1 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:0 toItem:vc.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1 constant:0];
    NSLayoutConstraint *con2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:0 toItem:vc.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1 constant:0];
    NSLayoutConstraint *con3 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:0 toItem:vc.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:1 constant:0];
    NSLayoutConstraint *con4 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:0 toItem:vc.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:1 constant:0];
    NSArray *constraints = @[con1,con2,con3,con4];
    [self.view addConstraints:constraints];
}
```

I call switchToNewView from a button in the initial view controller (the one you have labeled as ViewController) like this,

```
-(IBAction)doStuff:(id)sender {
    ContainerController *cc = (ContainerController *)self.childViewControllers[0];
    [cc switchToNewView];
}
```

Comment: Is your IB set up the same as mine? Are you using manual segues?

Comment: I think it's close but the view controller doesn't show up directly in the container. It's more off to the corner.

Comment: @Keith, actually, I'm not using the segues sat all. I have them setup in the storyboard so the controllers will automatically have the correct size (in  the storyboard for layout purposes), but then as you can see in the code, I just instantiate the controllers and add them manually as children. Are you using my category method to size the views?

Comment: Yes I am using the constrainViewEqual method. It doesn't appear to be working for me. I must be missing something.

Comment: @Keith, did you create a category on UIViewController, and put that constrainViewEqual: method in it?

Comment: That's probably my problem, I put it in the SwitchViewController. I've never set up a category before. Is there a lot to it?

Comment: @Keith, no, it's easy. You add a new file, but choose "Objective-C Category" instead of "Objective-C class". On the next screen put whatever name you want in the top text field labeled "Category" (I usually use something like "extras" or "additions" for the name), and use the pull down in "Category on" to put in UIViewController. Drop the code I posted into the .m file, and declare the method as usual in the .h file. Make sure you import the category into the controller where you use it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51539/discussion-between-keith-and-rdelmar)

Answer (score 0):

You can add the new detail viewControllers to the storyboard and configure the size of them to match the container from the interface builder

[image: In utilities choose size - Freeform]

then

[image: In here you can specify the dimensions]

Segue from your switch view controller and the new view controller should only take up the size of that view.

I hope this helps,

Cheers,

Jim