# Embedding ViewController through Custom Segue to Container View(somewhat like replace segues)

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue, uicontainerview

Up till now, I was using the UISplitViewController form my application. To add a functionality  to hide(move out of screen to left) for the masterView I have created a custom view controller that contains two container view form masterView and detailsView. Things are working as expected.

Now At someplace I had used the replace segue to replace the details view. And here comes the problem. How can I create a custom segue that embeds a viewController to a container view like the replace segue does?

Comment: Look at my answer here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23318709/ios-container-with-multiple-views/23319656#23319656, and see if that's what you need.

Answer (score 3):

I usually create a custom segue like this:

```
@interface MyCustomSegue:UIStoryboardSegue

@end
@implementation MyCustomSegue

- (void)perform {

    UIViewController* src = (UIViewController*) self.sourceViewController;
    MyViewControllerClass* dst = (MyViewControllerClass*) self.destinationViewController;
    [src addChildViewController:dst];
    [src.view addSubview:dst.view];

    //This line uses FLKAutolayout library to setup constraints
    [dst.view alignToView:src.view];
}
@end
```

You should then be able to draw your custom segue in storyboard (it should appear in the segue menu when you release the mouse button after drawing the line).

This is the simplest way i could think of, you can customize your source view controller to have a custom container view (instead of src.view) and a reference to the destination view controller.
You can also write your custom AutoLayout constraint code instead of using FLKAutoLayout (which is really great BTW).

Comment: Dont forget to call `[dst didMoveToParentViewController:src];` this is manditory when adding a child view controller.

Comment: This seems to require you to explicitly perform each of your custom segues, right? Mine don't automatically get called.